# Python socket closed before all data have been consumed by remote

Tags: python, sockets

I am writing a Python module which is communicating with a go program through unix sockets. The client (the python module) write data to the socket and the server consume them.

```
# Simplified version of the code used
outputStream = socket.socket(socketfamily, sockettype, protocol)
outputStream.connect(socketaddress)
outputStream.setblocking(True)
outputStream.sendall(message)
....
outputStream.close()
```

My issue is that the Python client tends to finish and close the socket before the data have been effectively read by the server which leads to a "broken pipe, connection reset by peer" on the server side. Whatever I do, for the Python code everything has been sent and so the calls to send() sendall() select() are all successful...

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I can't use shutdown because of mac OS

EDIT2: I also tried to remove the timeout and call setblocking(True) but it doesn't change anything

EDIT3: After ready this issue http://bugs.python.org/issue6774 it seems that the documentation is unnecessary scary so I restored the shutdown but I still have the same issue:

```
# Simplified version of the code used
outputStream = socket.socket(socketfamily, sockettype, protocol)
outputStream.connect(socketaddress)
outputStream.settimeout(5)
outputStream.sendall(message)
....
outputStream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
outputStream.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

IHMO this is best done with an Asynchornous I/O library/framework. Here's such a solution using [circuits](https://github.com/circuits/circuits):

The server echos what it receives to stdout and the client opens a file and sends this to the server waiting for it to complete before closing the socket and terminating. This is done with a mixture of Async I/O and Coroutines.

**server.py:**

```
from circuits import Component
from circuits.net.sockets import UNIXServer

class Server(Component):

    def init(self, path):
        UNIXServer(path).register(self)

    def read(self, sock, data):
        print(data)

Server("/tmp/server.sock").run()
```

**client.py:**

```
import sys

from circuits import Component, Event
from circuits.net.sockets import UNIXClient
from circuits.net.events import connect, close, write

class done(Event):
    """done Event"""

class sendfile(Event):
    """sendfile Event"""

class Client(Component):

    def init(self, path, filename, bufsize=8192):
        self.path = path
        self.filename = filename
        self.bufsize = bufsize

        UNIXClient().register(self)

    def ready(self, *args):
        self.fire(connect(self.path))

    def connected(self, *args):
        self.fire(sendfile(self.filename, bufsize=self.bufsize))

    def done(self):
        raise SystemExit(0)

    def sendfile(self, filename, bufsize=8192):
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            while True:
                try:
                    yield self.call(write(f.read(bufsize)))
                except EOFError:
                    break
                finally:
                    self.fire(close())
                    self.fire(done())

Client(*sys.argv[1:]).run()
```

> In my testing of this it behaves exactly as I expect it to with no
>   errors and the servers gets the complete file before the client clsoes
>   the socket and shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

After a discussion with a colleague aware of the C sockets (in cpython the socket module is a wrapper for the C sockets) he spoke about this http://ia600609.us.archive.org/22/items/TheUltimateSo_lingerPageOrWhyIsMyTcpNotReliable/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable.html (that's how it is done in PHP internal for the record)

TL&DR: shutdown + quick poll + close or ioctl(SIOCOUTQ) on linux