# How to recv large files using socketserver?

Tags: python, windows

Server side recv and send back data for client:

```
import socketserver

    class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

        def handle(self):
            try:
                data = b''
                while True:
                    package = self.request.recv(4096)
                    if not package:
                        break
                    data = data + package
                self.request.sendall(data)
            except ConnectionError as conError:
                print(conError)

    class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
        pass

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        HOST, PORT = "localhost", 50007
        print('Server start work!')
        server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
        ip, port = server.server_address
        try:
            server.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Server stop by Keyboard Interrupt.')
```

Client side read txt file, send it to server and wait reply:

```
def send_msg(data):
    import socket
    HOST = 'localhost'   
    PORT = 50007             
    reply = ''
    try:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.connect((HOST, PORT))
            s.sendall(data)
            while True:
                data = s.recv(4096)
                if not data:
                    break
                reply = reply+data.decode()
    except OSError as err:
        reply = err
    finally:
        return reply
#some.txt is big txt file
with open(r'some.txt', 'rb') as of:
    print(send_msg(of.read()))
```

But the realization of this "hang" after the last chunk of data. My question is, what needs to change, that would get all of the data.

Comment: Please consider using an Asynchronous Framework such as [circuits](https://github.com/circuits/circuits) or [Twisted](https://github.com/twisted/twisted)

Comment: I also implements a *very* similar solution that *would* probably do what you want here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620681/python-socket-closed-before-all-data-have-been-consumed-by-remote/30621445#30621445

Comment: Thanks, but both are not included in the framework is a basic set of pothon 3.4, which is not acceptable for the task at hand.

Comment: If this is not done by means of socketserver I will try to implement my server using only socket. 
Yet perhaps there are options?

Comment: Not important send back the received data, since they will be processed on the server side. It is important to get them.

Comment: You need this to work on Python 3.4?

Comment: Yes, it need to work on Python 3.4.

Comment: The frameworks I mentioned above work perfectly fine with Python 3.4 :) What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: He probably works fine. But it must be installed, which is not acceptable for this project. Socketserver there is a standard set of packages.

Comment: After sending the data you have to close the TCP connection in that direction so the other side knows there's no more data coming. Otherwise the `recv()` blocks in waiting for additional data.

Comment: I just don't have time to debug hand-crafted poorly designed Socket I/O code really :/ Please consider at least using AsyncIO which is part of the Python 3+ standard library!

Comment: Interrupting the connection is working, thank you. But later, to respond to the same client on the work done if the new connection will be in a new thread?

Comment: I found the description on the Internet [echo server](http://habrahabr.ru/post/217143/) works asynchronously, perhaps someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem as follows in the first 10 characters I'm sending the data size to receive and server-side checks the received data, if it is sent by the client less, then continue to receive data.

So you need modify server side:

```
import socketserver

    class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

        def handle(self):
            try:
                 package = self.request.recv(4096)
                 data_size = package[:10].strip(b'0')
                 data = package[10:]
                 while len(data) < int(data_size):
                     package = self.request.recv(4096)
                     if not package:
                       break
                 data = data + package
                 self.request.sendall(data)
            except ConnectionError as conError:
                print(conError)

    class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
        pass

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        HOST, PORT = "localhost", 50007
        print('Server start work!')
        server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
        ip, port = server.server_address
        try:
            server.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Server stop by Keyboard Interrupt.')
```

Client side:

```
def send_msg(data):
    import socket
    HOST = 'localhost'   
    PORT = 50007             
    reply = ''
    try:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.connect((HOST, PORT))
            s.sendall(str(len(data)).encode().zfill(10)+data)
            while True:
                data = s.recv(4096)
                if not data:
                    break
                reply = reply+data.decode()
    except OSError as err:
        reply = err
    finally:
        return reply
#some.txt is big txt file
with open(r'some.txt', 'rb') as of:
    print(send_msg(of.read()))
```